# Is Firebase's confirmPasswordReset() necessary with sendPasswordResetEmail()?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm implementing authorization with Firebase and using sendPasswordResetEmail(). The sendPasswordResetEmail portion works fine - it sends a link to the email that the user can click and change their password.

However, in Firebase's documentation for the method it says:

> To complete the password reset, call firebase.auth.Auth.confirmPasswordReset with the code supplied in the email sent to the user, along with the new password specified by the user.

This seems to be misleading, as it implies that calling confirmPasswordReset() is necessary.

Some of the research I've done seems to be that it is only necessary when we implement custom logic (i.e we want a code "4567" to be sent in the email rather than a link).

The documentation seems vague here.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#sendpasswordresetemail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to use the `confirmPasswordReset()` method if you use your own specific web page **instead of** the standard web page proposed by Firebase which is hosted at a specific URL in your project's Firebase Hosting domain and which looks as follows:

[image]

You can use your own specific web page in two ways:

1. By modifying the standard "Password reset" email template and customizing the action link URL to redirect the user on your own web page. You do that in the Firebase console, by opening the "Templates" tab of the Authentication part of the console. See also this [documentation item](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714).
2. By implementing an email action handler page as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler). See bullet #2: "Handle password reset requests by first verifying the action code with `verifyPasswordResetCode`; then get a new password from the user and pass it to `confirmPasswordReset`"